# Call another stored procedure and set to local variable and use like table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to call one stored procedure previously created and set `SYS_REFCURSOR` output into local variable (another stored procedure), I want to use this new variable like a table. I need to apply some wheres and filters

In this stored procedure, I'm trying to call a remote stored procedure then use it like variable:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE getmovimientosagenteres (
    primerdia      IN   STRING,
    ultimodia      IN   STRING,
    idbusqueda     IN   INT,
    identificador  IN   INT,
    tipo           IN   INT,
    result         OUT  SYS_REFCURSOR
) AS
    variable1 SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    variable1 := sch_descargas_app.getmovimientosagente(primerdia, ultimodia, idbusqueda, identificador, tipo,
                                       result);
    IF
        identificador = 1 AND tipo = 0
    THEN
        OPEN result FOR SELECT
                            *
                        FROM
                            variable1;
    END IF;
END;
```

My original stored procedure had the same logic, it is a fragment:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE getmovimientosagente (
    primerdia      IN   STRING,
    ultimodia      IN   STRING,
    idbusqueda     IN   INT,
    identificador  IN   INT,
    tipo           IN   INT,
    result         OUT  SYS_REFCURSOR
) AS
BEGIN
    IF
        identificador = 1 AND tipo = 0
    THEN
        OPEN result FOR SELECT DISTINCT
                            id_supervisoria,                      --0
                            nom_supervisoria,                     --1
                            id_agente,                            --2
                            nombre_agt,                           --3
                            f_pago_rbo,                           --4
                            num_poliza,                           --5
                            ramo,                                 --6
                            CASE
```

Comment: Your approach is fine and will work. Did you face any issues?

Comment: I don't see how it could work. `variable1` is not a table or view, so compilation will fail with *ORA-00942: table or view does not exist*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this will be possible, unless the refcursor has a predefined column list.

Simpler version of your test case:

```
create or replace function demo_get_refcursor
    return sys_refcursor
as
    resultset sys_refcursor;
begin
    open resultset for
        select 'Hello' as col from dual;

    return resultset;
end;
/

create or replace procedure demo_use_resultset as
    first_resultset  sys_refcursor := demo_get_refcursor();
    second_resultset sys_refcursor;
begin
    open second_resultset for
        select * from first_resultset;

end;
/

Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

SQL> show errors
Errors for PROCEDURE DEMO_USE_RESULTSET:

LINE/COL   ERROR
---------- -----------------------------------------------------------
6/9        PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
6/23       PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

`variable1` is not a table or view, so compilation fails with *ORA-00942: table or view does not exist*.

If you wrote a table function that accepted a refcursor as input in order to return each row, the function won't know how to define the record, because it's not defined until runtime. (Or is it? If the column list is known at compile time, that changes things.)

Perhaps in 19c you could dynamically create and populate a private temporary table after parsing the ref cursor with `dbms_sql` and then query, but this will be quite a project and I am not even sure that approach will work.

Comment: Thanks my friend @William Robertson, you gave me some ideas and I have tried with Bulks but that didn´t work, so i took a simple way and I created ahother result    OUT  SYS_REFCURSOR, thank you